# Semantic MediaWiki 2.2: which extensions versions to use?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am busy upgrading SMW 1.9.2 to version 2.2. How do I know which version to use of the accompanying extensions like Semantic Forms or Semantic Extra Special Properties?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the [SMW docs](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extensions):

> Various MediaWiki extensions are available for further extending
>   Semantic MediaWiki with additional functionality, and some basic
>   extensions of MediaWiki are generally useful for employing SMW.
>
> Most extensions are not maintained by the SMW Project. Please see the
>   extension's main page and installation files to find out whom to
>   contact for support and where to report bugs. Questions related to
>   these extensions can be discussed on the mailing list or forum for the
>   extension (where specified), or on the Semantic MediaWiki user mailing
>   list.

So, in case that you don't find the relation between your SMW version and the version of each extension in the Semantic MediaWiki user mailing list or the forum for the extension, you should look at the official docs for every extension or contact the developers of each extension, as there is not official reference about the relation you're looking for.